# No known class method for selector mainFrame

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, webkit

I'm sure this is a noob question but I've read countless similar problems and not found an explanation specific to this error. I therefore post in the hope of helping future googlers.

I want a clicked button (OSX, Cocoa) to launch a URL in a WebKit WebView. I am using an AppDelegate and the (boilerplate, works-for-everyone-else) code in AppDelegate.m is:

```
- (IBAction)goClick:(id)sender {
    [[WebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
}
```

The compile-time error is **No known class method for selector mainFrame**.

I discovered if I create an Outlet in my AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *wvOutlet;
```

it works with:

```
[[self.wvOutlet mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
```

So it all works with an instance (`self.wvOutlet`) method but not with the method `mainFrame` on the class `WebView`.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`[WebView mainFrame]` is attempting to call the **class method** `+mainFrame`. No such class method exists.

`[self.wvOutlet mainFrame]` is calling the **instance method** `-mainFrame`. This is correct.

Comment: Yep, I know. My question is why all the documented examples use `[[WebView mainFrame]` and in what case that works? UPDATE: I see now I have mistyped webView as WebView so it is an instance method in the examples!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misspelled `webView` (an instance) as `WebView`.

Solution: declare the outlet `webView` in your `AppDelegate.h` file:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
```

Disclaimer: not yet tested!